# Possible danger and security issues with input type="hidden" with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security, httprequest

I'm using in my project Spring MVC and Thymeleaf. Let's say I want to achieve very simple usage - editing user's form. I use SessionAttributes:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/")
@SessionAttributes(value={"user"})
public class UsersController implements Serializable
```

in request GET I,ve got simple mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"user/{id}", "{user/{id}/}"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String edit(Model model, @PathVariable(value="id") Long id, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
    String username = SecurityUtils.getLoggedUsername();    //for example, Spring Security
    User user = userService.getByIdAndUsername(id, username);
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "admin/user";
}
```

Simply enough - check if session logged user has permission to edit user with specified ID (in this example - only his ID). Field with id will not be populate on his HTML form via "hidden" field, it will be stored in SessionAttributes and merged after calling POST method. 
So far so good. But there comes a problem. What if - lets say - "very smart" user insert in his HTML debugger / generate a POST request with manually added hidden input with name = "user.id" (or general = "[object name].[object property] and call POST method? SessionAttributes will not be merged, because in my HTTP request property 'ID' exists.

```
@RequestMapping(value="user/{id}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String action(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
```

In this way anyone is able to edit someone's ID (assuming ID of other user is known) and edit other user. How to secure this part of system?
For now I have only one solution - treat anyone user as potential burglar and check POST method in the same way as GET method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="user/{id}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String action(User user, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
        String username = SecurityUtils.getLoggedUsername();    //for example, Spring Security
        User otherButTheSameUser = userService.getByIdAndUsername(id, username); //remember to evict this user from hibernate session
        if(otherButTheSameUser!=null){
            userService.update(user);
        }
    }
```

This should be secure enough, but here comes SQL performance issue, because of double SQL checking querys. Is this a good way? Is there another way how to achieve that? Maybe merging @SessionAttributes with request object with sessionAttributes priority ? How to achieve that?

Comment: 1) The mapping with the trailing slash is redundant. 2) The entire approach needs to be reworked; the authorization check needs to happen when the modification is attempted. This would make the problem you have right now evaporate.

Comment: Just to note that this isn't something that applies only to Spring MVC but basically any framework that does binding of request parameters. With Spring Security for instance you could do a simple check if the current user is editing the same user (no SQL required for that just a `@PreAuthorize` annotation with a SpEL expression).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far I understand, you may leverage [DataBinder.setAllowedFields()](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html#setAllowedFields(java.lang.String...)) or [DataBinder.setDisallowedFields()](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html#setDisallowedFields(java.lang.String...)) methods. [Excerpt from javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html):

```
In the case of HTTP form POST data for example, malicious clients can
attempt to subvert an application by supplying values for fields or
properties that do not exist on the form. In some cases this could
lead to illegal data being set on command objects or their nested
objects. For this reason, it is highly recommended to specify the
allowedFields property on the DataBinder.
```

So, I suggest to try something like this:

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    // please check that it's really working
    binder.setDisallowedFields("user.id");
}
```

Comment: Yes, "setDisallowedFields" is a good solution, but as far as I understand you have to specify list of concrete fields, not put all of fields via "user.*" because any field in user's form that is allowed to modify won't change.

Comment: Yes, I've updated my answer. But I also tried to show that you can use asterisk as simple regexp.